# What's (if there is) the environment variable for /var/run/*.pid on Openshift Online 3?

Tags: openshift

Openshift Online 3 seems to limit the permission to run `/var/run/*.pid` and I like to know if there is an environment variable for this.

I've tried `os.environ['OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR']` and it cannot find `/var/run/*.pid` since it is really just he path to the repo...

Comment: What application or image are you trying to deploy? OpenShift Online doesn't allow you to run containers as root. Instead you are assigned a uid which the container is run under. Many images out there assume they can run as root even though they have zero need to. If this is your own image, you need to design it in a way that it doesn't require it be run as root.

Comment: @Graham Dumpleton sounds good, i assumed the container runs like a docker so i get the fake root permission

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton also how do i get my uid?

Comment: When you use Docker there is no fake root. You are running as root still but constrained within a container. If there was security vulnerability which allowed you to break out of the confines of the container, you would then be root on the host. This is part of why running as root in a container is a bad idea.

Comment: The uid is effectively random. What you should do is set up permissions on the basis that your processes will run as group (gid) of 0. That is, the root group. This occurs because a uid is assigned which is not usually in the passwd file, so Linux falls back to using group (gid) of 0. You can read more about requirements for images in https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.5/creating_images/guidelines.html and in particular section 'Support Arbitrary User IDs'.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton sorry i don't exactly know the technology behind a docker when it comes to permission management. is the environment variable to get my current running uid `OPENSHIFT_APP_UUID`? looks like my app crashed when I tried to use it.

Comment: Why do you think you need to know the uid? If you really need to know the uid, you can work it out by running ``id -u``, or if in an application through whatever API gives you access to C API call for ``getuid()``.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton because i was attempting to create a secured socket connection between the server application and the client side application.

Comment: I don't understand why you would need to know it for that. Is it just used as some additional pseudo secret piece of information sent with data across the connection? A INET socket connection isn't going to care about what uid a process runs as. If a UNIX socket connection then it is by definition local to the pod and could't be used to talk to a client side process.

Comment: I see. Well I just made an websocket for it anyways so it works now.